# Rhandsontable in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, data-visualization, rhandsontable

EDIT: I included observeEvent() in server.R as described in this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzE1JmC0F6Q. 
 It works partially. When I update A and B, the graph gets updated, but the columns C,D and E are giving wrong values and the number of rows keep growing. Any help is appreciated.

I have 2 columns A and B. The user has the option to drag and drop values into A and B , and hence I am using rhandsontable (Source: https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/)

I have the code below for the ui.R and server.R.
The app basically has an editable table and a ggplotly output. Based on what I enter in columns A and B, columns C,D and E should get updated automatically based on some formula which I have included in server.R. When I run this code, the graphs and the columns don't update. What should I be doing?

ui.r

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4, rHandsontableOutput("table")),
    column(4, plotlyOutput("plot"))
    )
  ))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  df<- data.frame(A=c(9,15,25,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,75,85,95,105,120,125),
                  B=c(0.5,1.5,3,8,16,23,30,36,43,58,64,78,92,98,99,100))

  for(i in 2:(nrow(df))) 
  {
    df[i,3]<-df[i-1,1]+(df[i,1]-df[i-1,1])/2
    df[i,4]<-(df[i,2]-df[i-1,2])
    df[i,5]<- scientific(df[i,4]/df[i,3]/100,digits=3)
  }

  datavalues<-reactiveValues(data=df)

 output$table <- renderRHandsontable({

    mytab <- rhandsontable(datavalues$data, colHeaders=TRUE, rowHeaders=TRUE)
    return(mytab)
  })


  observeEvent(

    input$table$changes$changes,
    {
      xi= input$table$changes$changes[[1]][[1]]
      datavalues$data<-hot_to_r(input$table)

      for(i in 2:(nrow(df)))
      {

        datavalues$data[xi+i,3]<-datavalues$data[i-1,1]+(datavalues$data[i,1]-datavalues$data[i-1,1])/2
        datavalues$data[xi+i,4]<-(datavalues$data[i,2]-datavalues$data[i-1,2])
        datavalues$data[xi+i,5]<- scientific(datavalues$data[i,4]/datavalues$data[i,3]/100,digits=3)
      }

    }
  )




  output$plot<-renderPlotly({

    plt<-
      ggplot(datavalues$data,aes(A,B))+
      geom_point()+
      geom_line()+
      xlab("A")+
      ylab("B")

    p<-config(ggplotly(plt),mathjax = 'cdn')
    p

  })
```

Comment: I suspect much of the problem lies inside your `for` loop in `observeEvent`. Can you explain a bit more about what the intended behavior is? When you change edit a value in a specific row for column A or B, do you want columns C, D, E to update just in that same row? Can you describe more about why you have the `for` loop? Since the loop increases to `nrow(df)` and you add `xi` in your row index it makes sense that additional rows are added for columns 3-5...

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for catching it, as you mentioned, the problem was inside observeEvent. xi= input$table$changes$changes[[1]][[1]] is not needed. had a couple of other questions.

1. How do make columns C,D and E read only?

2. I want to change the column names into latex form. I am trying to use the latex2exp package, not sure where to include it

3.When I hover over a data point, I want to get something like (a,b) instead of datavalues$data[,3]:a datavalues$data[,4]:b

Comment: You might want to edit your question or submit a new question to cover everything, but I'll try to provide a bit more here. Columns C, D, and E are essentially read only, in that you currently overwrite the values if changed anyways. But to grey it out and make "read-only" you can add `%>% hot_col(col = 3:5, readOnly = TRUE)` after your `rhandsontable` statement.

Comment: I'm less familiar with the `latex2exp` package, but would look around SO for assistance, or post a new question. Finally, the labels for hover-over would likely come from column names. In my version running, it shows `A:55 B:36` over 2 rows. To reproduce what you have, it might help to update your posted question. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thank you! I posted another question and linked this question as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60896726/rename-rhandsontable-headers-in-latex-form